# Runtime Polymorphism - Arrow operator accessing the wrong member?

Tags: c++, run-time-polymorphism

I have the following classes in my program:

```cpp
class base {
public:
    int bval;
    base() {
        bval = 1;
    }
};

class deri: public base {
    int dval;
public:
    deri() {
        dval = 2;
    }
};
```

And a function `f` that takes pointer to object of class `base` and size of array pointed by it:

```cpp
void f(base *arr, int size) {
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++, arr++){
        cout << arr->bval << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

This is the main:

```cpp
int main() {
    base a[5];
    f(a, 5); // first call

    deri b[5];
    f(b, 5); // second call
}
```

The output for first call is `1 1 1 1 1`, which is correct.

But the output for second call is `1 2 1 2 1`, which is quite unexpected to me. It seems as if the value of `dval` is getting printed in place of `bval` for every second iteration of `for` loop within the function `f`.

Furthermore, if I include another private data member `int dval2` in class `deri`, the output to second call is `1 2 65535 1 2` every time I execute it (so 65535 doesn't look like any random value).

**Why is this behaviour exhibited by arrow operator**?

Comment: You pass the pointer as a `base` pointer, so the pointer arithmetic does not fit your `deri` array.

Comment: Sorry I misread the question. I have edited my comment. I still suggest to use std::vector and let f() take a `const std::vector<deri>&`.

Comment: @ypnos I would appreciate it if you could explain the pointer arithmetic taking place as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pass the pointer as a `base` pointer to `f()`, so the pointer arithmetic does not fit your `deri` array.

At this point: `for(int i=0; i<size; i++, arr++)`, only the size of `base` is added to `arr`, because `arr` is a `base` pointer.

It does not matter in this case what type of objects are really stored; they are not looked at when increasing the pointer value.

Two options that would help:

1. Use C++ containers. E.g. `std::vector<deri> b(5)` and `void f(const std::vector<deri> &vec)`.
2. Pass an array of pointers. In this case, when the pointer is accessed with arrow-operator, polymorphism can take place. Note that your base class needs a `vtable`, which you will obtain by defining and declaring a virtual destructor (the vtable is not needed to provide the expected output, but for several other reasons).

Comment: So are the members accessed by pointer arithmetic behind the scenes, even though we specify a name?

Comment: The member access is not your problem, the loop is where it goes wrong!

Comment: @KashinathPatekar, Because Base* gets bound at compile time